# Prove that matrix commutativity is sufficient for commutativity of matrix integral?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Statement**:

If $A(t)\cdot A(\tau) = A(\tau)\cdot A(t)$ for all $t$ and $\tau$, then $A(t)\cdot \int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma = \big(\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma \big) \cdot A(t) $.

**Attempt**:

Let $A(\sigma)\cdot A(\phi) = A(\phi)\cdot A(\sigma)$ for all $\sigma, \phi$.

Integrate both sides from $\tau$ to $t$ with respect to $\sigma$. Then,
$\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma)\cdot A(\phi) d\sigma = \int_{\tau}^{t} A(\phi)\cdot A(\sigma) d\sigma \implies \big(\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma \big) \cdot A(\phi) = A(\phi)\cdot\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma)d\sigma.$ Since the statement assumed holds for all $\phi$, let $\phi = t$, we have $A(t)\cdot\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma = \big(\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma \big) \cdot A(t)$.

Does this prove the statement correctly?

Also, would it be okay to just directly take the integral from $A(t)\cdot A(\tau) = A(\tau)\cdot A(t)$ with respect to $\sigma$ from $\tau$ to $t$ without first assuming dummy variables for arguments of both A?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need extra variables. $A(t)\cdot\int_\tau^t A(\sigma)\,\mathrm d\sigma = \int_\tau^t A(t)\cdot A(\sigma)\,\mathrm d\sigma$ [move the constant inside the integral] $= \int_\tau^t A(\sigma)\cdot A(t)\,\mathrm d\sigma$ [matrix commutativity] $= \left(\int_\tau^t A(\sigma)\,\mathrm d\sigma\right)\cdot A(t)$ [move the constant outside the integral].

Comment: Oh, I see...sorry for a stupid question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ansered by Rahul]

$A(t)\cdot \int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma) d\sigma $ (**LHS**)

$\implies \int_{\tau}^{t} A(t)\cdot A(\sigma) d\sigma $

$\implies \int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma)\cdot A(t) d\sigma $ (by matrix commutativity)

$\implies \big(\int_{\tau}^{t} A(\sigma)d\sigma\big)\cdot A(t) $ (**RHS**)